# Command that works fine typed into terminal does not work as a bash function

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a function which is meant to keep a record of every program I've installed (really, I'm interested in keeping track of dependencies). I've tested out my command in a terminal and it works just fine:

`dnf install sc | tee -a ~/Scripts/dnf_install.log`

Note that sc is just the program I chose since I happened to want to test out a few spreadsheet programs (without bloating my computer with unremoved dependencies) and it's got a short name.

Anyway, so I want to make this a function so I put in my .bashrc the following:

```
# easier install with logging
function install () {
    dnf install $1 | tee -a ~/Scripts/dnf_install.log
}
```

However, I always get this error:

```
ryan: ~ $ sudo install sc
[sudo] password for ryan:
install: missing destination file operand after ‘sc’
Try 'install --help' for more information.
```

After trying to narrow things down a bit, I'm pretty sure that the offending part of the code is `dnf install $1` and not the part afterwards.

Can anyone explain to me what I'm screwing up and how/why the command is being treated differently inside a function than directly inputted?

Edit: issue solved. As don_crissti pointed out, "sudo forks/execs a new shell that doesn't know about your function." So I put sudo inside the function and also changed $1 to "$1" for good coding practice. I did not know this was a duplicate since I didn't know the issue had to do with sudo.

Comment: Trying wrapping the function with `set -x`/`set +x` so you can see the exact commands being run; I find that often useful when debugging shell scripts.

Comment: Also, you should [quote the variable there](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) or else you can end up with strange issues due to word splitting.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, but all I get with set -x is:
++ printf '\033k%s@%s:%s\033\' ryan localhost '~'
followed by 
++ printf '\033k%s@%s:%s\033\' ryan localhost '~'
 and I really have no idea what that means.

Comment: Should be something along these lines: https://gist.github.com/xiongchiamiov/34a1e38423242e0e92bdccc1bd0238db

Comment: `sudo` forks/execs a new shell that doesn't know about your function so it will run the `install` executable from `/usr/bin` (which needs target and destination hence it complains about missing destination).

Comment: If I put set -x and set +x inside the function itselfand source my bashrc then I don't get any extra feedback at all.

Comment: @don_crissti - thanks for that explanation. I put sudo inside the function itself and that seemed to solve things. Can you make that a response so I can choose it as the solution?

Comment: @don not so sure about the duplication, as in this case it was also an overload of an existing command (otherwise the error message might have been more obvious)

Comment: If you solved your own problem, you should post it as an answer, not an edit to the question. Or maybe let @don_crissti post the answer as it was his comment that solved it.